# Why does running as Administrator matter as far as getting my site to build and run?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-3.5, administrator, runas

When I start VS2013 as Administrator, and then do a Rebuild of my ASP.NET project, I am able to get my site running again (would not run in non-administrator mode).

Why? What difference happens when running as Administrator that bypasses or is able to overcome the errors that otherwise occur?

Comment: Are you configured to load into IIS? And is the app-pool configured under a different user than your own? Reconfiguring IIS required elevated permissions. Connecting a debugger to a process running under a different user requires elevated permissions as well.

Comment: The site runs under IIS Express, if that's what you mean. I don't know anything about app pools or swimming in them. The code seems to (it's all new to me) first "impersonate" a login temporarily, while showing the Login page.